# How to center collected legends in multiple columns using ggolot2 and grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

[I have created a plot with 2 rows and multiple columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TeBH.png) Each column shows something different, as reflected by the column headings. I use the `patchwork` package to collect the legends, but all the legends are clumped into the middle of the image. How can I center each of them inside the relevant column?

The plot layout is created with

```
comb = imm300 + str300 + res300 + imm1200 + str1200 + res1200  & theme(legend.position = "bottom")
comb + plot_layout(guides="collect", ncol=3)
```

and in theme, I have specified

```
 legend.box = "vertical"
```

Comment: You are using `patchwork`. If you want to center the legend under each column I would suggest to not use guides = "collect". Instead remove the guides for each of the plots in the first row using `guides(fill = FALSE)`.

Comment: Oh of course! Thank you!